How do I withdraw my winnings from the bitcoin.org draw promotion
This is the message I received in my email///
Incredible news!
Funds have been processed and are now accessible in your account.
A Bitcoin transfer of 4.70195576 BTC has been credited to your account.
To proceed, request the withdrawal of funds.
Account Number:
I need to know how to access my funds please.or even my account.

To me, this looks like the preamble to an advance fee fraud, the email is a lie, there is no money.

So are the bitcoin.org promotions or draws a scam

Email addresses are easily faked. Moreover, Bitcoin.org is not an official Bitcoin website. There are no official Bitcoin websites as Bitcoin is decentralised. Bitcoin.org is now run by a somewhat hadowy private individual whose identity is not public. Most likely some criminal is faking his email address to trick inexperienced people.

See https://bitcoin.org/en/scams
